# What am I supposed to do after the "Defending the rift" quest in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I finished the mission and watched the shaman get taken by the tentacle. I went ahead and jumped into the big swirly thing and got stuck after that. Apparently there is some NPC supposed to be there when you finished the mission? Also apparently there is an NPC who gives you a quest to go back to Orgrimmar. I didn't find either of those and am really stuck.

What am I supposed to do after the "Defending the rift" quest?

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the below video how the quest is supposed to end and figure out if you really are stuck:

In cases of bugged quests there are a few things you can try. If you just want to get unstuck you could abandon quest, use your **hearthstone** and try the quest again.

However if you really want that quest completed and get yourself unstuck you should contact Blizzard by **submitting a ticket**. Explain the situation and they will get you out with completed quest, it can be quite time consuming if they are busy though.

If all else fails or you've tried restarting the quest and don't want to wait for a gamemaster, one thing you can try is to repair the game using **wow repair tool** in your game folder. This will ensure that all of your game files are complete and fix any errors it finds.

Comment: Jumping right to running a repair seems excessive - the first resort should always be to abandon and re-do the quest. Or, if that doesn't work or is highly impractical (raid quest or whatever), open a GM ticket.